# How to calculate the average from a text file for every year in python?

Tags: python

So this is my text file and i want to calculate the average for every year:

```
1969    324.000
1970    330.190
1970    326.720
1970    327.130
1971    326.970
1971    331.200
1971    329.430
1971    335.770
1971    337.600
```

And this is my Code that i got from another question but it keeps erroring:

```
In[2]: result = {}
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
       year, num = line.split()
       year = int(year)
       num = float(num)
       try:
           result[year].append(num)
       except KeyError:
           result[year] = [num]

In[3]: for k, v in sorted(result.items()):
   print('Year: {}\tAverage: {:.2f}'.format(k, sum(v) / len(v)))
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fra02.sek\Desktop\average.py", line 4, in <module>
year, num = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Your indentation is off after the line `for line in f` and some other areas.

Comment: Apparently you have a blank line at the end of the file. Either remove that line or add `if line.strip():` before splitting.

Comment: Can you tell me which lines or post it with correct indentation

Comment: I do have a blank line at the end i deleted it but nothing changed

Comment: Perhaps you did not delete all blank lines (including the last line break). Consider adding the `if` statement as I suggested above. If unsure, `print(line)` before splitting it and visually check if it is splittable.

Comment: Can you please post the full Code with everything as an answer. I will also give you a check mark.

Comment: It now says: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your indentation and added check for blank lines:

```
result = {}
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip()!='':
            year, num = line.split()
            year = int(year)
            num = float(num)
            try:
                result[year].append(num)
            except KeyError:
                result[year] = [num]

for k, v in sorted(result.items()):
    print('Year: {}\tAverage: {:.2f}'.format(k, sum(v) / len(v)))
```

Another solution, which I think is more readable:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    years = [line.split()[0] for line in lines if line.strip()!='']
    nums = [line.split()[-1] for line in lines if line.strip()!='']

for year in sorted(set(years)):
    values = [float(n) for y, n in zip(years, nums) if y==year]
    avg = sum(values)/len(values)
    print('Year: {}\tAverage: {:.2f}'.format(year, avg))
```

Comment: It still says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fra02.sek\Desktop\average.py", line 5, in <module>
    year, num = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: The problem is not blank lines, the error in this case would be `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`. There must be lines in the OP's text file with more than two fields.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille is likely correct. If you perform a `print` statement of `line` prior to it getting to the `line.split` then you can see how many values are in the resulting `list` from `line.split`. Post what you see

Comment: Its very big though